# Can't use macro define class in C++

Tags: c++, class, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to generate many sub-class which only has little difference, so I want to use macro to simplify my job. The macro define below:

```
#define DECLARE_SUB_CLASS(sub_class_name, base_class_name, value1) \
class sub_class_name:base_class_name \
{ \
public: \
    virtual int initialize(const void *); \
    virtual int run(const void *); \
    virtual void reset(); \
    virtual int output(const char*); \
    virtual void terminate(); \
private: \
    static const char m_szValue=#value1; \
};
```

I use it like this:

```
DECLARE_SUB_CLASS(RTCount13, RTCountBase, 13);
```

when I compiling with VC2005, it say

```
error C2065: 'RTCount13' : undeclared identifier
```

what's the problem?

Comment: The declaration of `m_szValue`, I guess you just copied wrong because its type should really be `char *` not just `char`?

Comment: In addition to string/char issue you have double semicolon, one while using the macro and another inside the macro definition.

P.S: why not use templates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use gcc -E (or similar for other preprocessor)

gcc -E prepro.cxx

```
# 1 "prepro.cxx"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "prepro.cxx"
# 17 "prepro.cxx"
class RTCount13:RTCountBase { 
  public: 
  virtual int initialize(const void *); 
  virtual int run(const void *); 
  virtual void reset(); 
  virtual int output(const char*); 
  virtual void terminate(); 
  private: 
  static const char m_szValue="13"; 
};;
```

You try to assign `"13"` to a char.

By the way you could also use a template instead of a macro to do the exact same thing your macro did (namely to declare but not define the methods). Here's a complete (trimmed down) example with separate method definitions.

```
#include <iostream>
class RTCountBase {};

template <class base_class_name, int v>
class RTCount: base_class_name { 
  public: 
   virtual int output(); 
   virtual void terminate(); 
  private: 
   static const int m_szValue=v; 
};

template <class base_class_name, int v>
int RTCount<base_class_name,v>::output(){ return m_szValue; }

template <class base_class_name, int v>
void RTCount<base_class_name,v>::terminate(){ std::cout <<" term "<<std::endl; }

typedef RTCount<RTCountBase,13> RTCount13; // typedef instead of macro
typedef RTCount<RTCountBase,14> RTCount14;

int main(){
   RTCount13 myc13;
   RTCount14 myc14;
   std::cout << "my13: "<<myc13.output()<<std::endl;
   std::cout << "my14: "<<myc14.output()<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using C++, you really should avoid using `#define` to do this. The C++ language has better ways to do this, for example:

```
template <class B, const char C>
class SomeClass : public B
{
public:
  virtual int initialize(const void *) {return m_szValue;}
  virtual int run(const void *) {return 0;}
  virtual void reset() {}
  virtual int output(const char*) {return 0;}
  virtual void terminate() {}
private: 
  static const char m_szValue=C; 
};
```

and then change this:

```
DECLARE_SUB_CLASS(RTCount13, RTCountBase, 13);

RTCount13 some_instance;
```

to:

```
SomeClass <RTCountBase, 13> some_instance;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a hash sign when defining your static char:

```
static const char m_szValue=#value1;
```

instead of

```
static const char m_szValue=##value1;
```

EDIT:

If m_szValue is meant to be a `string`, you need to define it outside the class declaration. I suggest you define a macro for this also to keep consistency:

```
#define DECLARE_SUB_CLASS(sub_class_name, base_class_name) \
class sub_class_name:base_class_name \
{ \
    //.....\
private: \
    static const char* m_szValue; \
};

#define DEFINE_SUB_CLASS_STATIC(sub_class_name, value1) \
    const char* sub_class_name::m_szValue = #value1; \
```

which you use like this:

```
//header file
DECLARE_SUB_CLASS(RTCount13, RTCountBase);

//impl file:
DEFINE_SUB_CLASS_STATIC(RTCount13, 13);
```

Comment: Two hashes for concatenation, one for stringification.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg so it should yield `static const char m_szValue=13`. What's wrong with that? `"13"` wouldn't make sense since it's not a char, but a char*.

Comment: I guess it depends on if the OP made a typo in the declaration of `m_szValue` or not. But since it's using the "sz" prefix I guess it should be a string.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't think you can initialize static strings *inside* the class declaration.

Comment: In C++11 you can do `static constexpr char m_szValue[] = "13";`, but for things like strings or other pointers you still need to define the variable outside the class.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yup, totally agree.